# Understanding function composition with negate

Tags: haskell, function-composition, negate

After reading through a page on Higher Order Functions from [an awesome site](http://learnyouahaskell.com/higher-order-functions#curried-functions) I am still having trouble understanding the negate function paired with function composition.

to be more specific, take this piece of code:

```
ghci> map (negate . sum . tail) [[1..5],[3..6],[1..7]]
```

which yields:

```
[-14,-15,-27]
```

I re-read the page again, but to be honest, I still have no idea how that line of code produced this answer, if someone could walk me through the process of this I would really appreciate it!

Comment: You can just remove an arbitrary number of functions from the left of such a pipeline, to see what's going on.

Answer (score 15):

```
map f [a,b,c] = [f a,  f b,  f c]
```

because `map f (x:xs) = f x:map f xs` - apply `f` to each element of the list.

So

```
map (negate.sum.tail) [[1..5],[3..6],[1..7]]
= [(negate.sum.tail) [1..5],   (negate.sum.tail) [3..6],   (negate.sum.tail) [1..7]]
```

now

```
(negate . sum . tail) [1..5]
= negate (sum (tail [1,2,3,4,5]))
= negate (sum  [2,3,4,5])
= negate 14
= -14
```

because `(f.g) x = f (g x)` and `.` is right associative, so `(negate.sum.tail) xs = (negate.(sum.tail)) xs` which in turn is `negate ((sum.tail) xs) = negate (sum (tail xs))`.

`tail` gives you everything except the first element of a list: `tail (x:xs) = xs`, for example `tail "Hello" = "ello"` 
`sum` adds them up as you expect, and
`negate x = -x`.

The others work similarly, giving minus the sum of the tail of each list.

Comment: I'm not sure calling `tail` the end of the list is fortunate. In other settings (Java, ...) "tail" is often used to denote the last node of a linked list, it might be better to use a wording that sets it clearer apart. Unfortunately, "all but the first element" is way too clumsy.

Comment: @DanielFischer Cheers. Edited to make `tail` functionality more explicit.

Comment: Great. I won't bother to un- and re-upvote to show my appreciation, though.

Comment: @Daniel Fischer this also confused me, as in C++ i always name the ending node of a linked list `tail`.

Answer (score 5):

To add a different perspective to AndrewC's excellent answer I usually think about these types of problems in terms of the [functor laws](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/4.6.0.1/doc/html/Prelude.html#t%3aFunctor) and `fmap`.  Since `map` can be thought of as a specialization of `fmap` to lists we can replace `map` with the more general `fmap` and keep the same functionality:

```
ghci> fmap (negate . sum . tail) [[1..5],[3..6],[1..7]]
```

Now we can apply the composition functor law using algebraic substitution to shift where the composition is happening and then map each function individually over the list:

```
fmap (f . g)  ==  fmap f . fmap g -- Composition functor law

fmap (negate . sum . tail)             $ [[1..5],[3..6],[1..7]]
== fmap negate . fmap (sum . tail)     $ [[1..5],[3..6],[1..7]]
== fmap negate . fmap sum . fmap tail  $ [[1..5],[3..6],[1..7]]
== fmap negate . fmap sum $    fmap tail [[1..5],[3..6],[1..7]]
== fmap negate . fmap sum              $ [tail [1..5],tail [3..6],tail [1..7]] -- As per AndrewC's explanation
== fmap negate . fmap sum              $ [[2..5],[4..6],[2..7]]
== fmap negate                         $ [14, 15, 27]
==                                       [-14, -15, -27]
```